# Datatable select length of row value for double

Tags: c#, select, filter, datatable, string-length

I know how to filter or select from datatable in C# as following. (If datatype of the column is string). Like following

```
Bool ReturnValue = DataTable.Select("LEN([" + ColumnName + "]) > 5").any();
```

Above code, if any of the rows containing value has length greater than 50 characters then it will give output as true.

I want to do something like above with double type. Here I have column "columnName" which is of double datatype. In this case above code will give me an error.

> Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument
>   with possible 'Child' qualifier.

Because LEN() is not applicable for double type.
Anyone know how to do the same for double datatype column. E.g.

```
Correct: "abcdef"
Error: "123456"
```

Because first one is of string type and LEN() is applicable to it but not applicable for second case. because all are numbers there so the datatype of the column in datatable is double or int32 and LEN() doesn't work there.

Pls help
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "length" of double?

Comment: You must convert double to string to get length.

Comment: @jdweng How ? can you give some example?

Comment: ToString().Length > 50

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to DataSet:

```
DataTable.AsEnumerable().Any(r => r.Field<double>(ColumnName).ToString().Length > 5)
```

But calculating 'length' of double is very strange. E.g. `10` will have length equal `2`, but `1.2345` will have length equal to `6`

Comment: I tried it, but I have over 50 lac records and AsEnumerable is very much time consuming and it time outs session. So can not use it. thanks. any other solution

Comment: @Maharshi 1) clarify why you need to check 'length' of double 2) if you have lot of data neither DataTable select nor LINQ is good option. Because both will require pulling all data into memory. You should do verifications on server side

Comment: I have nvarchar(50) in table structure. Because i need to add NONCLUSTERED INDEX on that column, so can not set it to nvarchar(max). so can not do it from server side

Comment: 1) is still unclear 2) why you cannot run database query?

Comment: For that, first I will need to insert records into database table. right? It will give me following error. because I have nvarchar(50) and one of a rows containing over 100 chars like (12345656464621313256463..)

The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.

Comment: @Maharshi you have loaded 50 lac records into datatable. Where those records came from? Also why have double in datatable if you have string in database?

Comment: I am loading all data from excel file. And it has double type selected automatically because in excel file that column is containing only numbers.

Comment: @Maharshi either change database column type or apply `ToString` when you loading that field from excel to datatable